# boundingRectWithSize is wrong in Hebrew

Tags: ios, nsstring, hebrew

This method I built works perfectly in English.
Now I'm trying to support Hebrew as well, and `boundingRectWithSize` misses the height (gives me something too short)

Can't figure out why...

```
+ (void) setTextAndFitLabel:(UILabel *)label text:(NSString *)text
{
    [label setNumberOfLines:0];
    text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];
    [label setText:text];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: label.font};
    CGRect rect = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX )
                                           options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                                        attributes:attributes
                                           context:nil];
    if ([text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        rect = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
    }
    CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
    labelFrame.size.height = ceil(rect.size.height);

    NSArray *constraints = [label constraints];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstAttribute = %d", NSLayoutAttributeHeight];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [constraints filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if(filteredArray.count == 0){
        label.frame = labelFrame;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint =  [filteredArray objectAtIndex:0];
        heightConstraint.constant = ceil(rect.size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Boaz ahi! Did you figured this out? It's making me crazy ah

Comment: 3 years have passed... Don't remember... sorry...

Comment: Thanks anyway, I've decided to change my design to fixed-size fonts. Lol

Answer (score 0):

`-boundingRectWithSize` calculates just the amount of space needed to print a text.
When you ask the size of a `UI/Label/TextView/Textfield` you should take into account that they are views with specific properties, for instance a UITexView include some inset before printing the text.
After assigning the text call `-sizeToFit` or `-sizeThatFits:` after that ask for its frames.
I don't know why you need that, but it worth to mention that UILabel intrinsic content size is calculated on fully display assigned text.

Comment: When using autolayout unfortunately you need this.
But leave that - you didn't answer my question - why is `boundingRectWithSize` returns a good height in English and bad one in Hebrew on the same font...

Comment: That's not true, I have autoresizable table view cell in iOS7 that uses siteToFit to get the height of a label an update a constraint making TVC height dynamic. I guess that I did answer you question by saying that IMHO you are not using the correct method. http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html